# Not able to pass dynamic parameters for sorting multiple columns in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

This is my stored procedure

```
 [sp_Get_Data]
   (
   @IdParam INT, 
   @OrderBy varchar(50),
   @Direc varchar(4),
   )
 AS
 BEGIN
select 
   [LogID] //int
  ,[Address]   //varchar
  ,[State]    //varchar
  ,[City]
  ,[Zip]
  FROM LogData 
WHERE IdParam = LogID
order by 

  CASE @Direc 
    WHEN 'desc' THEN  
    CASE @OrderBy 
        WHEN 'LogID' THEN LogID 
        WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
        END 
    END 
    DESC, 
CASE @Direc 
    WHEN 'asc' THEN              
    CASE @OrderBy 
        WHEN 'LogID' THEN LogID 
        WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
        END 
    END 

EXEC [sp_Get_Data] @IdParam ='..' @OrderBy = 'LogID', @Direc = 'asc'   // WORKS FINE
EXEC [sp_Get_Data] @IdParam ='..' @OrderBy = 'Address', @Direc = 'asc'
```

Error:

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'xyz' to data type int.*

Instead of using this dynamic parameters for sorting if I pass

```
ORDER BY Address ASC ....
```

this works.

Is there something very basic that I am missing here?

Comment: I'm removing [tag:jquery]. By the way, it's better if you format your code properly

Comment: Could we see the rest of the code? Entire sp_get_data would be nice

Comment: @ Urban Björkman It's have added the relavent code & for note I am also passing IdParam  in the exec statement ...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for its own use, and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your first execution (using `LogID`) generated an execution plan using a `INT`. When your second call was executed, the precompiled execution plan encountered a data conversion exception.

One solution would be to cast `LogID` to a `VARCHAR` type in order to always encounter the same datatype:

```
(...)

CASE @Direc 
WHEN 'desc' THEN  
CASE @OrderBy 
    WHEN 'LogID' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), LogID)
    WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
    END 
END 
DESC, 
CASE @Direc 
WHEN 'asc' THEN              
CASE @OrderBy 
    WHEN 'LogID' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), LogID)
    WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
    END 
END 

(...)
```

But, normaly this kind of operations (`ORDER BY`) is done on the application side... unless you can justify such method with a significant performance improvement. I just want to be sure you know what you are doing.

Note: You could try using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of your stored procedure and not use the `CONVERT`, since the execution plan would be recompiled after every use. It could be less demanding to recompile the stored procedure after each execution instead of using all this `CONVERT`/`RIGHT`/`REPLICATE` tweak. You'll see.

Comment: Thanks ...made my day.. can you tell me or direct me any article that explains the detailed reason for this behavior ...just wanted to understand it better..

Comment: You can see this SQLAuthority post :http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/17/sql-server-case-statement-in-order-by-clause-order-by-using-variable/, more information should be found in the comments.

Comment: @Scorpio: read my note, you would not get ordering as expected after converting int to varchar. `int orders 1,2,11` but `after converting to varchar` it will `order as 1,11,2`

Answer (score 2):

Return value type of the CASE should be same. In the first instance it does not reach the Address, so it works. But for 'Address' it expects to be as same as LogId which is an int. So the conversion fails.

**NOTE:** ***Converting `LogId` to an `VARCHAR` type would sort the error `but it would not give you correct ordering` as numbers. So use the `RIGHT` function to tackle it like***

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',11) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LogID), 12)
```

([Here is DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d295c/1))

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY 
   CASE @Direc 
    WHEN 'desc' THEN  
    CASE @OrderBy 
        WHEN 'LogID' THEN RIGHT (REPLICATE('0',11) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LogID), 12)
        WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
        END 
    END 
    DESC, 
CASE @Direc 
    WHEN 'asc' THEN              
    CASE @OrderBy 
        WHEN 'LogID' THEN RIGHT (REPLICATE('0',11) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LogID), 12)
        WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
        END 
    END
```